# How to add a number to a integer element of two dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to create a two dimensional array that looks like this:

```
[1 10 20 30]
[2 11 21 31]
[3 12 22 32]
[4 13 23 33]
[5 14 24 34]
```

I hope you got the logic. Each column starts with numbers like `10` or `20` and goes down until `19` or `29`. I honestly don't understand how I should do this. I tried the following code before:

```
int arr[10][10], i = 0, j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        arr[i][j] = i;
    }
}
```

But the result is different from what I want. Could someone explain to me how can I create such two dimensional array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr[i][j] = 10*j + i;` ?

Comment: @nielsen, it will not agree for the first column

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the first column should actually start with `0`?

Comment: @mmixLinus no, it should start with 1

Comment: If you want a 5x4 array then why do you use a 10x10 array? Start by making sense out of that.

Comment: @Lundin This array shouldn't be 5x4, it's just an example. I think it obvious that Array should be at least 10x10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need one more variable.

```
int k = 0;
int arr[10][10], i = 0, j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        k = j*10 + i;
        arr[i][j] = k;
    }
```